# Eclipse Luna - Update Site for Eclipse Java Developer Tools

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

After a long love-hate relationship with eclipse, i got used to downloading Eclipse's blank "Platform Runtime Binary" and installing every single plugin myself (even the "Java Development Tools") over update sites. For the last years i was really happy with that solution.

Now i downloaded Eclipse Luna and i can't seem to find the "Java Development Tools" in the official update sites as in other releases. I searched in some other locations as well, but no luck.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDT is in the usual place.

For Luna the update site is 'http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna' and the JDT is in the 'Programming Languages' section - `Eclipse Java Development Tools'

Comment: That's where it used to be. But it just isn't, at least in my case. I see a lot of C/C++ plugins and some other, but no Java Development Tools or JavaScript Development Tools there. I double checked by searching on "Java" and even displaying installed plugins too

Comment: It is there for me, I checked before posting this. Do you have 'hide items that are already installed' checked?

Comment: I am not at my PC atm, but i double checked that too. I am sure that it isn't already installed, but still i unchecked that option and tried to find it again. But if you say it's there i will try again in the evening. Very strange

Comment: Tried again with a fresh download and all and had no problem finding it now. Don't know what happened, maybe i really overlooked it (really can't believe it though, considering that i checked like 10 times and googled like 30 minutes for a solution). Nevertheless, your answer is correct. Thanks!